# Reference for basic result on algebraic dimension of a complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

In his book *Complex Geometry*, Huybrechts states and proves a classical theorem of Siegel that a compact complex manifold of complex dimension n has algebraic dimension at most n. Unfortunately, I don't understand his proof, so I'd like another reference - but it's proving surprisingly difficult to turn up. I can't find it in Griffiths-Harris or Voisin. Did I just miss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Shafarevich's [*Basic Algebraic Geometry II: Schemes and Complex Manifolds*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3ZlrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=function+field+transcendence+degree+complex+manifold&source=bl&ots=OYzgQ-2C9j&sig=ACfU3U1HYzh-KdAHRCLg21X3X2N20Q4AxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiliI3Up4rjAhVDShUIHdphAfoQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=function%20field%20transcendence%20degree%20complex%20manifold&f=false). The result you're looking for is Theorem 3 on page 175.